# CUDA: Can I use FLT_MAX in my kernel

Tags: cuda

Is it safe to use the constant FLT_MAX from float.h in my cuda kernel to initialize a variable. So, the usage I have is as follows:

```
#include <float.h>

__global__ void my_kernel()
{
    ...
    float min = FLT_MAX

    // read some value
    if (val < min) min = val;
}
```

Is it safe to do so? I am guessing the underlying bit representation should be the same but I am not sure if there is some issue with overflow here.

Comment: Sorry! I got my forums wrong!

Comment: You can initialize it to +Infinity. Also, floats don't overflow the same way as integers. Integers go from MAX_INT to MIN_INT (or zero if unsigned), while floating point numbers stay at + or -Infinity.

Comment: That did the trick. I initialized it to 0x7f800000.

Comment: If you like this, why not provide an answer?